# Where to find Path of the price element in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, theme

I have installed a payment method extension and it requires adding the following;
[image]

Can I please know what element to input and where to find the path?

Thank you

Comment: which extension is this one you are installing?

Answer (score 0):

It is asking to give a class selector of an element around which you want to render this payment-related element on the product page.

You can set ".price-box" in case you want to render an element near price.